# Sync function on nodejs to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a check script with a MySQL query, the problem is that the authorization function is executed before it was done MySQL query so it returns always false. How can fix it?

```
 mysql= require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({});


 check_auth(req.query.s){
 var sql = "query to mysql";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results.length  > 0) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        } 
}

io.configure(function () {
io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
var auth=check_auth(req.query.s);
console.log(auth);
if (auth===true){
    return callback(null, true);
}else{
return callback('notauth',false);
}
});
});
```

EDIT: new structure as Jarema but still don't work

```
 mysql= require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({});


function check_auth(input, callback){
 var sql = "query to mysql";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        if (results.length  > 0) {
            callback(null,results.values);
        }else{
            callback(null, false);
        } 
}

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
        check_auth(req.query.s, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                //handle that error somehow. we dont not structure of Your func.
                return console.log('error:(');

            }
            if(result === false) {
                return callback('notauth', false);
            } else {
                return callback(null, result);;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

error is

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Query._callback (myserver.js:54:12)
at Query.Sequence.end (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:78:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:143:8)
at Query.EofPacket (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:127:8)
at Protocol._parsePacket (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:205:24)
at Parser.write (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:62:12)
at Protocol.write (node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:37:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:73:28)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
```

line 54 is

```
 callback(null,results.values);
```

Comment: As the `query to mysql` is likely asynchronous, it can't be used to `return` a result for `auth`. You'll need to revise `check_auth` to accept and call a callback of its own, passing the result as an argument, and provide a `function` accepting `auth` as a parameter where `check_auth` is called.

Comment: Jonathan is almost for sure right. I extended answer to give You *probable* solution.

Comment: what is now Your error?
the first function works as intended?

Comment: still the same  callback(null,results); TypeError: undefined is not a function I added the error

Answer (score 1):

If check_auth query is still processing when next function/if statment is called, for me it means it's asynchronous. If it was synchronous, it would block code execution until its finished.

EDIT: As Jonatham mentioned, the query function itself is probably async. If You put it in 'normal' synchronous function, it doenst mean You can return inner async result to parent function, and from parent return it again. You have to deal with callbacks.

Here is PROBABLY working example, that for sure need adjusting, as we dont know what's inside auth function:

```
 mysql= require('mysql');
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({});


    function check_auth(input, callback){
     var sql = "query to mysql";
        connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
            if (err) callback(err);
            if (results.length  > 0) {
                callback(null, true);
            }else{
                callback(null, false);
            } 
    }

    io.configure(function () {
        io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
            check_auth(req.query.s, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    //handle that error somehow. we dont not structure of Your func.
                    return console.log('error:(');

                }
                if(result === true) {
                    return callback(null, true);
                } else {
                    return callback('notauth', false);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: if You use https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql module, You need a callback after query, or You would not get the result from it, as its async. Look how i structured query in given example. it looks like YOu try to treat async function sync, which is impossible.

Comment: you have now all my structure but i Don't undestand the auth var

Comment: updated. First of all - in the begining You try to call check_auth instead of define it (You dont have "function" statement). second, i updated my answer. If Your io.set callback accepts err and result, it should work.

Comment: It don't work at  if (results.length  > 0) {
      at this line->     callback(null, true);  TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: it would happen if when calling check_auth, You dont use callback, so instead check_auth(inputdata, function(input, function(err,result){})
you did: check_auth(inputdata) or something like this. Honestly, i dont understand why You even have first parameter for check_auth if You dont use it at all?

Comment: Up there is my new code with your sugestions but It don't whork